# How to see what is causing failcnt on tcpsndbuf

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, memory, openvz

I am seeing a failcnt on my tcpsndbuf by looking at the user beancounters. How am I able to see what is causing this failcnt?

I am experiencing problems with my server and I think that it is as a result of this so I really need to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is run [monbean.pl](ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/openvz/contrib/utils/monbean/monbean.pl) every five minutes from `cron`; when I see a problem, I know what time it happened, so I go and check the log files.